# Common Roles without Tenant for AspnetBoilerplate Framework c#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying create a common role in aspnet boilerplate by removing the tenantid from the abprole table but am getting an error while i try to login.

The error is in the account controller. wanted to know how can we override the aspnet boilerplate role.

I have tried removing the tenant id from the role also tried to tweak the account controller but still getting an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxAFX.png)

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: You need to remove `TenantId` references from your code too.

Comment: if you are in multi tenant mode and you are trying to remove tenantId you are not allowed to do such, otherwise if you are in single tenant why are trying to remove tenantId? the reason may help in order to provide a proper solution rather than removing a column

Comment: @thomi where can i share you a code. Thanks for replying